# Emacsでxとxに挟まれた空白を確認つきで削除したい

Tags: emacs

Emacsで“ある文字A”と“ある文字B”に挟まれた“ある文字C”を、確認つき（query）で削除するコマンドを教えてください。

具体例として、「2つの“x”に挟まれた空白1つだけを削除する」ことにします。これを実行するコマンドを教えてください。

ここで、バッファが以下の内容となっているとします。

```
x x x x y
```

望む結果は以下のとおりです。

```
xxxx y
```

たとえば`M-% x x RET xx RET`を実行した場合は、`!`で全部置換しても当然以下のようになり、要件を満たしません。

```
xx xx y
```

置換を2回実行するか、replace-search-functionを再定義するぐらいしか思いつかないのですが、よくあるシチュエーションで解がすでにあるのではないかと思ってお聞きします。

Answer (score 2):

`query-replace-regexp` のドキュメントによると

```
In interactive calls, the replacement text can contain `\,'
followed by a Lisp expression.  Each
replacement evaluates that expression to compute the replacement
string.  Inside of that expression, `\&' is a string denoting the
whole match as a string, `\N' for a partial match, `\#&' and `\#N'
for the whole or a partial match converted to a number with
`string-to-number', and `\#' itself for the number of replacements
done so far (starting with zero).
```

Lisp 式が書けるので、

```
\(x \)+x
```

を

```
\,(replace-regexp-in-string " " "" \&)
```

もしくは

```
\,(make-string (1+ (/ (length \&) 2)) ?x)
```

に置換することでできます。

Answer (score 1):

Emacs の正規表現には lookahead がないので `M-x query-replace-regexp` では無理っぽいですね。

私は必要なら、深く考えずに Elisp 書きます:

```
(while (search-forward "x x")
  (if (y-or-n-p "replace?") (replace-match "xx"))
  (backward-char 1)) ;; 最後の x に戻って検索しなおす
```

[文字列中のアイテムを置換したくない場合の定石は?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1709/) に Perl を呼び出して lookahead を使う方法があるようですが、これだと query なしで一気に書き換えることになります。

Comment: このとおり実行したら、以下のエラーとなりました。どこが悪いのでしょうか。

    Debugger entered--Lisp error: (args-out-of-range 1107 1136)
      replace-match("xx")
      (if (y-or-n-p "replace?") (replace-match "xx"))
      (while (search-forward "x x") (if (y-or-n-p "replace?") (replace-match "xx")) (backward-char 1))
      eval((while (search-forward "x x") (if (y-or-n-p "replace?") (replace-match "xx")) (backward-char 1)) nil)
      eval-expression((while (search-forward "x x") (if (y-or-n-p "replace?") (replace-match "xx")) (backward-char 1)) nil)
      call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)

Comment: エラーの問題は、emacs -qでinit.elを読まずに起動したところ起きなくなりました。私のローカル設定に問題があったようです。失礼しました。

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun whatever-you-want ()
  "Put proper explanation here"
  (interactive nil)
  (while (search-forward "x x")
    (if (y-or-n-p "replace?")
      (replace-match "xx"))
    (backward-char 1)))
```

とちゃんと関数として定義して実行してみましたが、期待された動きをすると思います
(camlspotterさんの投稿へのコメントにしたかったのですが、まだ reputation が足りなかったので独立した回答で)。

Comment: camlspotterさんにコメントしたように、私のローカル設定に問題があったようです。失礼しました。